# co-prime perfect power summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, mobius-function

The following [link](https://oeis.org/A001597/b001597.txt) shows 10000 perfect power.
I was wondering how many numbers are there less than $n$ that are perfect power and also co-prime with $n$. i.e. $gcd(n,k) = 1$.

In general I would like get to get sum of all co-prime perfect powers that are less than.

$$S(n) = \sum_{k,\gcd(k,n)=1}^{n} (n \bmod k)$$

How do I calculate this sum efficiently for any random $n$?

Comment: @reuns I am doing some work on perfect powers so I need help. You can see this as I have derived from my previous results. The questions that I have asked before. More over I was thinking to some extent of mobius function and all.

Comment: In number theory $p$ means prime. With $(n \bmod k)$ did you mean $n-k\lfloor n/k\rfloor$ ? Why do you care of this sum ? In number theory most problems don't have any answer, we need as much freedom as possible to modify the problem in order to reach something we can say something about.